# popup validation error msgs showing in main form not in popup how to solve it

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have a form it has one link ,when click on a link it opens a pop up window,in that i have a form,when validation fails on that form it must be show error msgs in the pop up only but the error msgs are showing in the main form.how to solve it.

i want to popup validation msgs in same popup.
why it is not showing error msgs in popup

pop up panel code is

```
    <rich:popupPanel id="lp" modal="false" autosized="true" resizeable="false" >
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Add New Doctor" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="controls">
        <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{rich:component('lp')}.hide(); return false;">
            X
        </h:outputLink>
    </f:facet>
                              <h:form id="drRegiForm">
            <h:panelGrid columns="4">

            <h:outputText value="Doctor Name" style="font-size: medium" ></h:outputText>
            <h:inputText value="#{doctorBean.doctorName}" id="doctorName" size="37" required="true"/>
            <h:message for="doctorName" />
            <br/>
            <h:outputText value="Place" style="font-size: medium"></h:outputText>
            <h:inputText value="#{doctorBean.place}" id="place" required="true"/>
            <h:message for="place"/>
            <br/>
            <h:outputText value="Phone Number" style="font-size: medium"></h:outputText>
            <h:inputText value="#{doctorBean.phoneNumber}" id="phoneNumner"/>
            <br/>
            </h:panelGrid> 
           <a4j:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{doctorBean.registration}" execute="" onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide()" />

                  </h:form>    <p>       
        <a href="#" onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide()"></a>

    </p>    </rich:popupPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have nested forms, get rid of them. You can keep just the main one and use `<a4j:region>` to limit the execution scope.